# Are battle bridges on any other ship besides the Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek

Battle Bridges are a seldom-seen component of the Enterprise, basically serving as a backup bridge in case the saucer and secondary hull are separated. From my experience, it is the only ship I've seen that has this.

Do any other starships have battle bridges or secondary bridges that act similar in function to the Enterprise's?

Comment: You mean (ships from) other classes, right?

Comment: Also, which Enterprise are you talking about?

Comment: One thing worth noting but not included in the answers below is that auxiliary control centers are really only necessary for *dramatic* purposes. It's established by implication and in some of the technical manuals associated with the series that a person with sufficient access rights can, if necessary, fly the ship from a PADD or a tricorder, or entirely by voice command.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Control of Federation starships can be executed from the main bridge or from an [Auxiliary Control Center](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Auxiliary_Control_Center). On starships such as the Galaxy Class starships, the Auxiliary Control Center is more robust and called a [Battle Bridge](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Battle_bridge).**

> Galaxy-class starships have a more robust auxiliary control center, called the battle bridge, which controls the stardrive section after a saucer separation. (TNG: "Encounter at Farpoint") We see the Enterprise D battle bridge three times in canon; Encounter at Farpoint, The Arsenal of Freedom and the Best of Both Worlds, Part II.

- The primary difference between an auxiliary control center and the designation battle bridge is due to the fact the battle bridge controls the stardrive section of the ship after a saucer separation.
- All Federation ships have an auxiliary control center as a backup control center should the bridge be lost, destroyed or taken over by a boarding party.
- The auxiliary control center can take control of the ship if the proper authentication can be obtained. This was done by Dr. Severin onboard the USS Enterprise in the episode "The Way to Eden". This happened far more often than the Federation probably liked.
- The Defiant-class starships also contain an Auxiliary Control section.

> Defiant-class starships also contain an Auxiliary Control section. In 2374, when the USS Defiant lost phaser control while under attack by a Jem'Hadar ship, Captain Sisko ordered Commander Worf to Auxiliary Control in order to target the phasers manually. (DS9: "One Little Ship")

- It is unclear if the [Prometheus-class](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Prometheus_class) which boast of the [Multi-Vector Assault Mode](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Multi-vector_assault_mode) had more than one battle bridge for each individual ship section, since the ship could still be computer controlled from the main bridge section. Since the individual components could be flow separately, even though it is not mentioned, they probably had their own battle bridge components.

Comment: According to the Next Generation Technical Manual, it's possible to control a ship from main engineering in an emergency.

Answer (score 4):

A quick search of [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Battle_bridge) shows that battle bridges exist on at least two classes of Federation Starships: Excelsior-class ships (including the USS Enterprise-B) and Galaxy-class ships (such as the USS Enterprise-D) both have battle bridges shown on screen.

Answer (score 2):

Constitution-class and Defiant-class ships also have an [Auxiliary Control Center](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Auxiliary_Control_Center), which serves a similar purpose (backup bridge), despite the latter lacking separation capability.

Comment: When you say constitution class I assume you mean the same ship type as the Enterprise from TOS. That ship never deprecated the saucer section from the engineering section, at least to my knowledge. I thought that separation was first introduced in TNG's Enterprise-D.

Comment: @GilKeidar - It didn't (they didn't have the budget for it), but the capability to do so is mentioned in The Apple (2x09) and in the Writers' guide.

Answer (score 1):

The Intrepid class has one too don't they?  The *Voyager* relaunch novels mentions that the Intrepid's were retrofitted with saucer separation meaning they would have one too and I if memory serves the book I am about to reference has its climax on Voyagers Battle Bridge.  I don't want to provide spoilers, but I think it happened in the last book [The Eternal Tide](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Eternal_Tide).

Comment: Why can't the primary bridge be the one the drive section after separation?    Then there is no need for a battle bridge.

Comment: @ThePopMachine because Star Trek always seem to like to portray the bridge as being at the very top of the saucer.  Though this makes almost no sense from a tactical perspective.  Since the main bridge is at the very top of the saucer, then after saucer sep, someone must handle the controls in the stardrive section.  This is called the battle bridge.

Comment: @Zoredache:   After separation, the top part of the drive section still has a portion of the saucer.   So for a hypothetical Intrepid class separation, the bridge could still be on the drive section.   Who has any evidence of where the cut line is?

Comment: I certainly don't recall the book specifying where the split occurs.  I also don't recall Intrepid Saucer Separation being mentioned anywhere else either so there may be no official (Canon or not) identification of that cut line.

Answer (score 0):

Battle bridges were designed for ships capable of independent warp capable combative readiness.

- The Excelsior class has a battle Bridge on Deck 19 (Generations)
  Any ship with saucer seperation capability and rejoining without a starbase, is presumably possessing an auxillary control room.
  Also in the event of an emergency; the ships main engineering can be utilized to serve as a makeshift bridge.